# php -f bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade not working in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, customer, migration, password

After migration from magento 1 to magento 2, I ran this command but it is not working. I am not able to login with customers passwords. Why the command is not working?

Comment: Any error showing ???

Comment: No error is showing. It displays finished but after when I try to login in the frontend, still I am not able to login with customer details.

Comment: Have you checked the customer detail on admin? is it migrated properly?

Comment: yes, that is migrated very well. Only password is not working.

Comment: php -f bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade is working in magento 2.3.4 version. But not working in magento 2.3.3 and below versions.